# Change data from aggregated to granular level

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregation-framework, aggregate-functions

My data is in the form:

[image]

To reproduce:

```
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS SALARY;
    CREATE TEMP TABLE salary
    (
     Employee varchar(100),
     Salary1 numeric(38,12),
     Salary2 numeric(38,12)
    );
   INSERT INTO salary (Employee, Salary1 ,Salary2)
   VALUES ('A1',100,300),('A2',200,300),('A3',300,450),('A4',400,600);
```

I want to divide it evenly (as we have data for 2 days of salary aggregated into 1 column) and cast it into a daily level data as below:

[image]

Hence, if you see for employee A2-Sum of salary for 3rd and 4th may would be 300 (150+150 from the 2nd table).
Any help/leads appreciated.

Comment: Do you *really* have a column called `[Salary- 1st May,2nd May]`? That is going to be awful to work with. How do you know what year that data is for? Why does the first column have a space between the day and the month, and the second does not? That's terribly inconsistent. Honestly, I think you need to get some (poor soul) one to manually do this.

Comment: No, ofcourse the data is reproduced. This problem is for a specific forecasting problem, where the forecasts are at a weekly level and I want to break it down to the daily level evenly.

Comment: Also [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Comment: Thanks, but i dont see how can I upload a table here, as I am not getting an option to insert table.

Comment: @user2458552, script the table as a `CREATE` statement and post as code along with `INSERT` statements for your example data.

Comment: Alternatively, @user2458552 , you can at least use well formatted tabular `text` or a markdown table.

Comment: @Dan Guzman - Added!

Comment: if the columns are just called `Salary1` and `Salary2` (rather than `[Salary- 1st May,2nd May]` and `[Salary- 3rdMay,4thMay]` respectively) how do you know what dates those values are for?

Comment: The column field names don't indicate the dates that we need to go for, it's known. For this example, its for the specific dates of 1st-2nd and 3rd-4th.

Comment: Lets just say we need to distribute the column values into preassigned dates grouped by employees

Comment: @user2458552, employee A1 in your desired results does not match your description. It seems 2022-05-03 and 2022-05-04 should be 150 (300/2) instead of 75.

Comment: *"it's known"* By who/what? You? That's no good for SQL Server. Where is it physically stored that `Salary1` is for the dates `2022-05-01` and `2022-05-02`? If it's not, then you **need** to store that data *somewhere*. Do you just have `Salary1` and `Salary2` columns? Is there a `Salary3`, `Salary4`? Perhaps a `Salary279`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A materialized [calendar table](https://www.google.com/search?q=calandar%20table) with the desired dates will facilitate generating the dates needed for the query. Without one, a [tally table](https://www.google.com/search?q=tally%20table) or CTE (as in the below example) is an alternative method.

```
DECLARE
      @StartDate date = '2022-05-01'
    , @DaysPerSalary int = 2;
WITH
     t10 AS (SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) t(n))
    ,tally AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) AS num  FROM t10 AS a CROSS JOIN t10 AS b CROSS JOIN t10 AS c)
    ,salary1 AS (
        SELECT Employee, Salary1 / @DaysPerSalary AS Salary
        FROM SALARY
    )
    ,salary2 AS (
        SELECT Employee, Salary2 / @DaysPerSalary AS Salary
        FROM SALARY
    )
SELECT DATEADD(day, tally.num-1, @StartDate), Employee, Salary
FROM tally
CROSS JOIN salary1
WHERE tally.num <= @DaysPerSalary
UNION ALL
SELECT DATEADD(day, tally.num-1 + @DaysPerSalary, @StartDate), Employee, Salary
FROM tally
CROSS JOIN salary2
WHERE tally.num <= @DaysPerSalary
ORDER BY Employee, Salary;
```